# Click to reveal and hide menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I asked a question yesterday about a click to reveal menu which got answered perfectly. However, I was wondering how I can make the div fade in when the text "project info" is clicked and then fade out again when "project info is clicked again". I know this is probably a very basic thing but i'm extremely new to javascript and jquery and would appreciate some help greatly. The html code is as follows:

```
<div  class="descinner">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showDesc">Project info</a>    
</div>
```

and the Javascript:

```
$('.showDesc').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $(this).next().toggle(); });
$('body').click(function() { $('.showDesc').next().hide(); });
```

Comment: Also there are some things with your html. For one you don't need to actually create a link, this can be a span or div and then styled to look like a link if you want. The other thing is, you should keep your styling (css) separated from the html. This will make it easier when debugging and viewing the code.

Comment: notice your first div has the line `class:"descinner;"` which should be `class="descinner;"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a custom function and call it onClick...inside that function you can put your fadeIn and fadeOut...and you especially can't do it with .toggle().

Comment: Thanks for the help, could somebody possibly edit the code so I can paste it in? Thanks. Dean

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)() method?

Like this:

```
$('.showDesc').click(function() {
  $('.info').fadeToggle();
});
```

This will show the `.info` div on the first click of `.showDesc`, and hide it on the second (and so on)..

Comment: I don't know that method, could you explain furthur? Thanks

Comment: @Dean It does the same as toggle but will fade the content out/in (depending on whether it is visible or not) over the supplied duration.

Comment: fadeToggle will simply alternate between hiding and showing the element with every call. If the element is hidden it will display it and if it's visible it will be hidden.. saving you the trouble of figuring out what to do..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [FadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) function. Use it on the element you want to fade in.

Answer (score 0):

you have jQuery animation functions: fadeIn and fadeOut. you can also use show and hide functions. just set the desired speed parameter

```
$('your_div').fadeIn(100);
$('your_div').fadeOut(100);
```